# CSS looks different in Firefox than Google Chrome, what can I do?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

For fun, I am doing a table with two cells in each row. And I want the cells in the first row to have the same picture, so I wrote in CSS:

```
tr:nth-child(1){
background-image:url("cat.jpg");
background-size:cover;
border-radius:10px;
}
```

And my HTML code looks like this:

```
<tr>
  <td>Ruta 1</td>
  <td>Ruta 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Ruta 3</td>
  <td>Ruta 4</td>
</tr>
```

So, you should have the same picture on each cell, which I have in Google Chrome.
But when I use this in Firefox, I get the same picture over two cells.

[Google Chrome](https://gyazo.com/8b409cf1fc70f102f8a9b95788d014d3), and [Firefox](https://gyazo.com/882c1ffc0be132aee43789132e59ac58).

Any clue of what this is about? Can I write something in my CSS do make it work for Firefox. thanks in advance!

Comment: Sätt bakgrunden på cellen `td`, inte på raden `tr` ... :)

Comment: Om jag skriver td:nth-child(1) så får jag den på de första cellerna i varje rad, vilket inte var min tanke. Ville ha samma bild på samma rad, olika bilder på varje rad.
Däremot så funkar tr:nth-child(1) td{} bäst.

Comment: Japp, så ska du göra. `tr:nth-child(1)` betyder inte att du sätter värden på cellerna `td`, det betyder att du menar första `tr`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply background to cells - `<td>` and not to rows - `<tr>`.

```
tr:nth-child(1) td {
    background-image:url("cat.jpg");
    background-size:cover;
    border-radius:10px;
}
```

You want each *cell* to have its own picture, not each *row*.

Answer (score 1):

In firefox don't set background-image or color in tr, It will make problems. Instead add to td.

```
tr:nth-child(1) td{background-image:url("cat.jpg");}
```